# Getting Rid of the Old/Worthless Data Center Equipment

Tags: networking, hardware

I have old and completely worthless routers/modules that are rotting in my office closet from various data center upgrades. I doubt anyone would want to buy this stuff (feel free to contact me otherwise), and even if I sold it, I'd probably spend more money shipping it. The inventory consists of a bunch of Cisco 3725's, 2651XM's, Pix525's, a vast array of corresponding modules and switches, and a plethora of 3.65 wireless radios and other manner of gear. Before I make several trips to the dumpster, I just wanted to know what everyone else does with old stuff like this. I'm sure someone somewhere can make use of this junk, or I can monetize it some other way either by way of tax write-off or something.

IT spring cleaning at its finest. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because e-waste disposal is something you have to ask your local municipal waste disposal service about.

Comment: We just call one of the local computer/electronic recyclers. They send out a truck and couple guys to haul it away.  I've never had them refuse to take something, computers, network gear, CRT/LCDs, projects, etc.

Comment: The answer also depends heavily on where you are; if you're in Europe, WEEE regulations will likely apply.  You can't just cart this stuff down to the dump and drop it in a skip, it has to be properly disposed of.

Comment: I'm not asking about HOW to dispose of networking equipment. I'm asking other admins what they do with their networking equipment. Disposal is most definitely an option, but I doubt that my local trash men would have any idea what other options I would have other than throwing it all out.

Comment: It still depends on where you are; and in any case, a mod has said the question is off-topic.

Comment: Miami, FL USA. The country that cares the least about proper disposal of anything. I'm sure I'd get a federal subsidy if I just dumped it in the ocean.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit - for anything potentially holding commercially sensitive material, it's properly destroyed. (Shred/furnace). It's just not worth the risk of it being recoverable.

For stuff that doesn't fall into that category - you may find a local geek community might have a use for it for 'playing with' in a workshop/hack space. Advertise it on freecycle or equivalent maybe?

Comment: This equipment is from so many years past that any data recovered off of these things would be completely worthless, and its all equipment running our internal infrastructure so no client data would be on anything. Freecycle sounds like an option. Maybe I can have someone get it out of my hair for me! :) Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but I'm also aware of some quite hair-raising incidents where people didn't realise that things like printers and photocopiers had hard disks in them...